# Can you use a Visual Studio Database Project in a Unit Test Project to setup a empty database for a functional test?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, unit-testing, sql-server-data-tools

For years we have used the following code to setup databases in a base class for our functional tests for our DAL, and this has worked extremely well for us.

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes the test class by creating the integration database.
/// </summary>
[TestInitialize]
public virtual void TestInitialize()
{
    DataContext = new DataContext(ConnectionString);

    CleanupPreviousTestRunDatabases();

    if (DataContext.Database.Exists())
    {
        DataContext.Database.Delete();
    }

    DataContext.Database.Create();
    DataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String.Format(Strings.CreateLoginCommand, DatabaseUserName, DatabasePassword));
    DataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String.Format("CREATE USER {0} FOR LOGIN {0}", DatabaseUserName));
    DataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String.Format("EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', '{0}'", DatabaseUserName));
}
```

However, using Entity Framework does not setup all components of a database and we would like to catch discrepancies between our EF DAL model and the actual database.

We use the SSDT tools / Visual Studio Database Project for all of our database work, and I know you can write SQL unit tests, and in those SQL unit tests, I have seen the ability to setup and create a database based on the database project itself. This is what I would like to do, but from our other functional test libraries.

I can reference the libraries and write some of the setup code, but what I'm looking for is:

a) How do I provide which Database project to use to deploy?

b) How can I specify connection string in code rather than an app.config, such as using localdb instead with a dynamically named database?

```
namespace Product.Data.Tests
{
    using Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    [TestClass]
    public class FunctionalTest
    {
        [TestInitialize]
        public virtual void TestInitialize()
        {
            SqlDatabaseTestClass.TestService.DeployDatabaseProject();
            SqlDatabaseTestClass.TestService.GenerateData();
        }
    }
}
```

The app.config in a SQL Unit Test Project doesn't contain any reference back to the original Database project used to create it, and decompiling some of the test code and seeing how it works, I don't see any indication. Does it assume there is only one database project in the solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With some direction from the links @Ed Elliott posted, I was able to make this happen. You will need to add `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac` as a assembly reference from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll` (Visual Studio 2015). It is part of the SSDT tooling, so I'm sure the path may be different for earlier versions.

```
[TestClass]
public class DatabaseTest
{
    protected string DatabaseConnectionString = $@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True";
    protected DatabaseContext DatabaseContext;
    protected string DatabaseName = $"UnitTestDB_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToUpper()}";

    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void TestInitialize()
    {
        var instance = new DacServices(DatabaseConnectionString);
        var path     = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(TestContext.TestDir, 
                                        @"..\..\..\Build\Database\Database.dacpac"));

        using (var dacpac = DacPackage.Load(path))
        {
            instance.Deploy(dacpac, DatabaseName);
        }

        DatabaseContext = new DatabaseContext(DatabaseConnectionString);
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public virtual void TestCleanup()
    {
        DeleteDatabase(DatabaseName);
    }
}
```

Then how it would be used for a functional test in a unit test project.

```
[TestClass]
public class CustomerTypeTests : DatabaseTest
{
    private CustomerType customerType;

    [TestInitialize]
    public override void TestInitialize()
    {
        base.TestInitialize();

        customerType = new CustomerType
                       {
                           Name = "Customer Type"
                       };
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AddOrUpdateCustomerType_ThrowExceptionIfNameIsNull()
    {
        ExceptionAssert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => DatabaseContext.AddOrUpdateCustomerType(customerType));
    }
}
```

Just a note to others, you should also setup your `Build Dependencies` so that your unit test project depends on the database project, ensuring it is built first and produces the correct `dacpac` file.

What this solves for us, is this gives us a true database, not one just based on Entity Framework's model, which lacks quite a lot of SQL constructs (to be expected), especially default constraints, indexes, and other important elements of a database. At our DAL layer, this is essential for us.

Comment: So `DatabaseContext` is your custom EF context that you've created separately from these tests?

Answer (score 5):

I think the process you have is a little over complicated (if I understand it correctly which I might not have!).

What I do for unit testing in ssdt is to:

- Build the solution
- Deploy each dacpac that I need to my dev instance
- Run the tests

To deploy a project there are a few ways, you can:

- Create a "Publish Profile" for each project and run that
- Right click on the project and choose publish
- Use a powershell script (or do it in code in your test initialize) to do a publish of the dacpac.

Once it is deployed run your tests, doing a publish of a dacpac (project) is pretty simple from code or a script, you can either:

- call sqlpackage.exe to do it for you
- use the dacfx api's to do the deploy (http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/deploying-a-dacpac-with-dacfx-api/)

If you control the publish yourself then it gives you a lot more control *plus* when you deploly using this you are testing the same deployment system that you will use in other environments (assuming you use dacpac's to deploy).

ed

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and the hyperlinks. I was able to make this work.